# JPA many to many mapping

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to understand JPA many to many mapping from this link.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

However i have a hard time mapping my head around the following line

```
employee.getProjects().add(association);
```

what should the method implementation for getProjects look like ?
It looks like there is a method chaining here  ?
Should getProjects return an ArrayList of project/s so we can invoke a add method on it ?

Should the getProjects be implemented in employee class ?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773159/many-to-many-jpa-mapping-inserting-but-not-fething-the-child-collections?rq=1

Comment: It is just a regular public getter method for the attribute  `projects`. You may chose any kind of `Collection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look in this exemple: we consider that "employee" entity has many "projects" so as we represent it in java like ;

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
 private List<ProjectAssociation> projects;
```

so the function getProject() return list of "projects" associated to an "employee", so then we have to add an "association" to each "project" how ? : like this :

```
   employee.getProjects(); // to get "projects" of each "employee"
  employee.getProjects().add(assosiation); //to add an "association" for 
   each "project"
```